# How do I trigger a function on the click of a div id javascript/lQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to click a div and have a javascript function reset
Every time I click the id="home" button I want countME() and countDE() to reset to 1/5

html

```
<button type="button" onClick="countME()">Click up</button>
<button type="button" onClick="countDE()">Click down</button>
<div id="home"><button>home</button></div>
<p>Clicks: <a id="clicks">1</a>/5</p>
```

js

```
var clicks = 1;
function countME() {
    clicks += 1;
    if(clicks >= 5 ){
          clicks = 5; 
      }
    document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
 }
 function countDE() {
    clicks -= 1;
    if(clicks <= 1 ){
          clicks = 1; 
      }
    document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
 }
```

[jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2my16ube/)

Comment: The element with `id='home'` is a div

Answer (score 1):

Just the same, you were doing before:

```html
<button type="button" onClick="countME()">Click up</button>
<button type="button" onClick="countDE()">Click down</button>
<div id="home"><button onClick="resetDE()" >home</button></div>
    <p>Clicks: <a id="clicks">1</a>/5</p>
```

```
 var clicks = 1;
    function countME() {
        clicks += 1;
        if(clicks >= 5 ){
              clicks = 5; 
          }
        document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
 }
   function countDE() {
        clicks -= 1;
        if(clicks <= 1 ){
              clicks = 1; 
          }
        document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
 }

 function resetDE() {
        clicks = 1;
        document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
 }
```

In this case you don't need jQuery.